# How can I develop an Apache Cordova/PhoneGap app without a device

Tags: cordova

When developing a Cordova/PhoneGap app I'd like to be able to develop with Chrome on my laptop without a device.  Is there a way to do that?

For example with some sort of "cordova.stubs.js" that simulates the native portion of the API.  Of course this is just for my development cycle and after iterating on my laptop for a while I would deploy and test on a real device or with a device emulator.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the Ripple emulator yet?

http://emulate.phonegap.com/

Comment: Exercise caution! The Ripple Emulator at emulate.phonegap.com only works with older versions of PhoneGap! 


The more up-to-date Ripple emulator has moved to http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/


This article can help you get started: 
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn

Answer (score 0):

One fast alternative for simulate in android is: www.genymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're by any chance working on a MacBook, you can use the iPhone Simulator to run your PhoneGap app and then connect to it remotely.

1. In the iPhone Simulator home screen, tap on Settings > Safari > Advanced. Enable the Web Inspector option.
2. In your Mac's Safari, click on Develop -> iPhone Simulator -> index.html

   - As far as I know, this only works on iOS 6 and above.

Answer (score 0):

go to [here](http://phonegap.com/products/#desktop-app-section) and you can open it in chrome browser and also you can use  [this](http://phonegap.com/products/#mobile-app-section) if you have mobile and can debug using `weinre`